# How to make request with sql filter to Service Bus to post a message?

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, servicebus

I have topic with two subscriptions on Service Bus. One of them has this sql filter:
[image]

The other subscription, this sql filter:
[image]

When I send a message via Service Bus, the filter works:
[image]

But when I send a message via request, the message gets "lost" (does not reach any of the only two subscribers).

This is my code to send a message:

```
private readonly HttpClient _client;

public ServiceBusSender()
{
    _client = new HttpClient();
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(string body)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri($"https://{my-uri}/{my-topic}/messages"));
    
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8");
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", my-auth);
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Host", my-uri);
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("IdStatus", "154"); //I have also tried ("IdStatus", "'154'") and it doesnt work
    
    request.Content = new StringContent(body);

    return await _client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong to send the filter via request?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the filter details (you are just showing the name and type of the filter).

Comment: Also, when sharing the screenshots please have the chosen language in Azure Portal as English.

Comment: @GauravMantri Question edited with more information. My organization does not allow changing the language, for that I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, just submit with `"\"YOURFILTER\""`, in my case:
`"\"154\""`